# How to find missing sequence of datetime from file through walk

Tags: datetime, awk, sh

Actually i want to find find sequence break of datetime from file, and add blank lines in place missing entry.

*Example file*

2017-09-07 01:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:45:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:45:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:45:00 10 0

*output should be,*

2017-09-07 01:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:45:00 10 0

four blank lines for 2nd hour

2017-09-07 03:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:45:00 10 0

four blank lines for 4th hour

2017-09-07 05:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:45:00 10 0

Comment: Yea, so what is your specific problem?  Moreover, what language you are using actually?

Comment: ksh->awk @Prisoner

Comment: Maybe you can tag them in your question, that should help you get your answer quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Using `gawk`

```
awk '
    function get_dt(v)
    {
          gsub(/[-:]/," ",v); 
          return strftime("%F %T",900 + mktime(v))
    }
    {
        current_dt=$1" "$2
    }
    next_dt != "" && current_dt != next_dt{
        while(current_dt!=next_dt)
        { 
            # print next_dt, "this is new"
            # here is your blank line
            print ""

            next_dt=get_dt(next_dt)
        }
    }
    {
        next_dt = get_dt($1" "$2)
    }1
  ' file
```

**One Liner**

***Input***

```
$ cat infile
2017-09-07 01:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:45:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:45:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:45:00 10 0
```

***Output***

```
$ awk 'function get_dt(v){gsub(/[-:]/," ",v); return strftime("%F %T",900 + mktime(v))}{current_dt=$1" "$2}next_dt != "" && current_dt != next_dt{while(current_dt!=next_dt){ print ""; next_dt=get_dt(next_dt)}}{next_dt = get_dt($1" "$2)}1' infile
2017-09-07 01:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:45:00 10 0




2017-09-07 03:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:45:00 10 0
```

***If you need timestamp then***

```
$ awk 'function get_dt(v){gsub(/[-:]/," ",v); return strftime("%F %T",900 + mktime(v))}{current_dt=$1" "$2}next_dt != "" && current_dt != next_dt{while(current_dt!=next_dt){ print next_dt" this is new"; next_dt=get_dt(next_dt)}}{next_dt = get_dt($1" "$2)}1' infile
2017-09-07 01:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:45:00 10 0
2017-09-07 02:00:00 this is new
2017-09-07 02:15:00 this is new
2017-09-07 02:30:00 this is new
2017-09-07 02:45:00 this is new
2017-09-07 03:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:45:00 10 0
2017-09-07 04:00:00 this is new
2017-09-07 04:15:00 this is new
2017-09-07 04:30:00 this is new
2017-09-07 04:45:00 this is new
2017-09-07 05:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:45:00 10 0
```

Comment: what if file has entry with doent match regular expression like 


  0 0 0.00
2017-09-25 01:30:00 13 0 0.00
2017-09-25 02:30:00 13 0 0.00
2017-09-25 03:30:00 13 0 0.00

@Akshay Hegde

Comment: how can i apply reg ex pattern to pick/process line which match only date patern, like /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/
@Akshay Hedge

Comment: `NF && !/^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/{next}` put this line beginning so that any other pattern will be skipped, if there is field and pattern does not match skip such line, pattern which you mentioned above, look from starting of line because `^`

Answer (score 0):

In GNU awk:

```
awk '
function foo(str) {       # converts $1 $2 to epoch time
    gsub(/[-:]/," ",str)
    return mktime(str)
} 
NR==1 {                   # set initial time
    p=foo($1 " " $2)
    next
} 
{
    q=foo($1 " " $2)      # current time
    while(q!=p+900) {     # current should be previous + 900 s 
        print ""          # if not, print empty record
        p=p+900           # and increase p by 15 mins
    }
    print
    p=q                   # current is new previous
}' file
2017-09-07 01:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:45:00 10 0




2017-09-07 03:00:00 10 0
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Shortest ***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'[[:space:]:]' '!a[$1,$2]++ && h && $2-h>1{ print "\n\n\n" }{ h=1 }1' file
```

The output:

```
2017-09-07 01:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 01:45:00 10 0




2017-09-07 03:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 03:45:00 10 0




2017-09-07 05:00:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:15:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:30:00 10 0
2017-09-07 05:45:00 10 0
```

Comment: what if just `2017-09-07 05:15:00` is missing, I think OP wants to print newline wherever there is gap in datetime, looks like 15min interval

Comment: @AkshayHegde, you said *I think OP wants* - you can't read the OP thoughts, that's your subjective. So I would adjust or delete my answer if the OP will say "Actually, I meant another logic, this won't give me the desired result"

Comment: Sure dear, sorry that was what I perceived from his/her post

Comment: how can i apply reg ex pattern to pick/process line which match only date patern, like /^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/
@AkshayHegde Roman Perekhrest